# iterate through an array using assembly and find the sum of the elements

Tags: assembly, x86

im new to assembly and im trying to iterate through an array and find the sum as i go along and put the sum into eax. This is my code so far.

```
.data
    myArray db 1, 2, 3



.code
main PROC

    mov eax, 3      
    mov ebx, 0              
    mov esi, OFFSET myArray     

top: add ebx, [esi]

    add ecx, 1              
    dec eax                 
    jnz top                 

done:
    mov eax, ebx
    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
```

Im pretty sure im using the OFFSET wrong. When i debug the program ebx is still 0 even though ive added [esi] to it. Like i said im pretty sure im using offset wrong but any tips on how to fix it so the [esi] is added to ebx with each iteration. Registers when i have a breakpoint at mov eax, ebx: EAX = 00000000 EBX = 00090603 ECX = 009B1008 EDX = 009B1005 ESI = 009B4000 EDI = 009B1005 EIP = 009B1025 ESP = 0082FE18 EBP = 0082FE24 EFL = 00000246

Answer (score 3):

For a MASM-style assembler, your use of `OFFSET` is fine, but

- The loop forgets to advance the pointer to the next array element! Perhaps `add ecx, 1` was meant to be `add esi, 1`?
- The `add ebx, [esi]` instruction will add a whole **dword** to EBX.
  Because *myArray* comprised **bytes**, you need to extend the values

Both errors explain why the dump shows `EBX = 00090603` in the end (00030201h + 00030201h + 00030201h = 00090603h).

```
  xor   eax, eax            ; Sum
  mov   ecx, 3
  mov   esi, OFFSET myArray
More:
  movzx edx, byte ptr [esi]
  inc   esi                 ; Move to next byte
  add   eax, edx            ; Sum += Item
  dec   ecx
  jnz   More
```

Since in the end you want the result in EAX anyway, then also add to EAX instead of to EBX in the loop.

### Data directives `db`, `dw`, `dd`

When you define an array of **bytes** using the `db` directive as in `myArray db 1, 2, 3` the memory at the address *myArray* will show next 3 bytes:

```
1, 2, 3
```

To fetch a single array element and have it stored in a 32-bit register you would use `movzx edx, byte ptr [esi]` which is an instruction that reads 1 byte from memory, extends the byte into a dword *padded with zeroes on the left*<sup>1</sup>, and then leaves the result in the 32-bit register.

When you define an array of **words** using the `dw` directive as in `myArray dw 1, 2, 3` the memory at the address *myArray* will show next 6 bytes:

```
1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0
```

To fetch a single array element and have it stored in a 32-bit register you would use `movzx edx, word ptr [esi]` which is an instruction that reads 2 bytes (aka word) from memory, extends the word into a dword *padded with zeroes on the left*<sup>1</sup>, and then leaves the result in the 32-bit register.

When you define an array of **dwords** using the `dd` directive as in `myArray dd 1, 2, 3` the memory at the address *myArray* will show next 12 bytes:

```
1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0
```

To fetch a single array element and have it stored in a 32-bit register you would use `mov edx, [esi]` which is an instruction that reads 4 bytes (aka dword) from memory, and then leaves the result in the 32-bit register.

<sup>1</sup> Although in the register the zeroes are padded on the left, in memory the zeroes are padded on the right since x86 is a little-endian architecture. The low byte(s) come(s) before the high byte(s) when seen in memory.

```
EDX = 00000001h   myArray : 1, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but i get 2 errors when i debug:  MSB3721: The command 'command' exited with code 1 and A2009 syntax error expression on line 18. Do you know why these arise and how to fix them

Comment: @RobbieWoodhams Read the edit to my answer. MASM requires `byte ptr` instead of `byte`.